# Will an http response with no http caching parameters be cached

Tags: http, caching

I see a lot of sites that return an html page with no caching parameters in the header.  No pragma, no cache-control, no e-tag, no expiration date... nothing...  From the http 1.2 spec, it seems like this means it can be cached but I am not sure.  Any one know the exact rule that governs caching if there are no cache directives in the response?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. The http 1.1 spec allows for a scenario where there are no cache directives.  In this case the receiving cache can use a Heuristic Expiration algorithm. For me that is the answer.  It is cache-able.  However, I have found that firefox and Chrome will not cache it.  I did see a post that found the chrome source that sets "DEFAULT_CACHE_TIME = 300" which I believe is about 5 minutes or maybe it's 5 ms.. I don't know...  Anyway, I just needed to know if the spec allowed a cache to cache an object that had had no cache directives.

Below quote is from:
http://home.anadolu.edu.tr/~egermen/EEM534/Refreshment%20policies%20for%20Web%20content%20caches%20.pdf
Otherwise, no explicit
freshness lifetime is provided by the origin
server and a heuristic is used: the freshness lifetime
is assigned to be a fraction (HTTP/1.1 mentions
10% as an example) of the time difference between
the timestamp at the DATE header and the time
specified by the LAST-MODIFIED header, subject
to a maximum allowed value (usually 24 h, since
HTTP/1.1 requires that the cache must attach a
warning if heuristic expiration is used and the
object’s age exceeds 24 h).